# JAXB How to exclude marshalling of nested type that is the same as XmlRootElement type?

Tags: xml, jakarta-ee, jpa, jaxb, entity

I have such structure of entities:

```
@XmlRootElement
class Provider { 

   @OneToMany 
   Set<ProviderService> providerServices; 

   // other fields and properties 
}

@XmlRootElement 
class ProviderService  { 

   @ManyToOne 
   Provider provider; 
   @ManyToOne 
   Service service; 

   // other fields and properties 
}

@XmlRootElement 
class Service { 

   @OneToMany  
   Set<ProviderService> providerServices; 

   // other fields and properties 
}
```

How can I prevent JAXB from generating second (the same) Provider XML/JSON object when marshalling Provider entity?

```
<provider>
  <!-- somthing --> 

  <provider-service> 
    <provider /> <!-- this repeats the same data as root provider UNWANTED -->  
    <!-- something --> 
    <service /> <!-- this is ok --> 
  </provider-service> 
</provider>
```

Moreover using just @XmlTransient on Provider attribute in ProviderService isn't a solution as I will want to have this Provider element generated when marshalling Service entity as root element with list of its ProviderServices (in this case I don't want to have repeated nested Service entity data)

The best solution will be somthing like specifying on root entity @XmlExcludeNestedTypes({Provider.class}) on Provider and 
@XmlExcludeNestedTypes({Service.class}) on Service class but I suppose such annotation doesn't exists? any workround for this solution maybe writing some customization of marshalling?